# Sorting visualization - how to solve circular dependency?

Tags: c++

I'm writing sorting visualization. I want it to handle events and update screen while the algorithm is running. I have a Controller class which has SortContext attribute. I want SortContext's sort method to take reference to the controller so it can use methods `update` and `isAppRunning` but I get an error:

> Controller has not been declared

How can I make it work?

**Controller.hpp**

```
class Controller {

private:
  SortContext context;
  View view;
  std::vector<Sortable> data;

  bool algorithmRunning = false;

  void handleEvents();

public:
  Controller();
  void update();
  bool isAppRunning();
};
```

**SortContext.hpp**

```
class SortContext {

private:
  std::unique_ptr<SortStrategy> strategy;
  static const std::vector<std::function<std::unique_ptr<SortStrategy>(void)>> algorithms;

public:
  void chooseStrategy(int algorithmId);
  void sort(std::vector<Sortable> &data, Controller &controller);
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Forward declare `Controller` class in *SortContext.hpp* and include *SortContext.hpp* in  *Controller.hpp*:

```
#include "SortContext.hpp"

class Controller {

private:
  SortContext context;
  View view;
  std::vector<Sortable> data;

  bool algorithmRunning = false;

  void handleEvents();

public:
  Controller();
  void update();
  bool isAppRunning();
};
```

```
class Controller;

class SortContext {

private:
  std::unique_ptr<SortStrategy> strategy;
  static const std::vector<std::function<std::unique_ptr<SortStrategy>(void)>> algorithms;

public:
  void chooseStrategy(int algorithmId);
  void sort(std::vector<Sortable> &data, Controller &controller);
};
```

Don't include *SortContext.hpp* where you include *Controller.hpp* otherwise you'll get a redefinition error:

```
#include "Controller.hpp"

int main()
{
    // use your classes
}
```

Here you can see a [**live demo**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CG5M9dyAnnHxVxuv)

Comment: Now I got *‘SortContext’ does not name a type* in controller.hpp. If I forward declare `SortContext` in `Controller` I get *field ‘context’ has incomplete type ‘SortContext’*. I fixed this using unique_ptr to `SortContext` in `Controller`. Is this a good way to do this?

Comment: @Gh0st you can only use forward declarations for use with pointers or references, since `context` is an object it won't work. You may need to `#include SortContext.hpp` in `Controller.hpp`.

Comment: I include `sort_context.hpp` in `controller.hpp` but still get an error *error: ‘SortContext’ does not name a type*. I'm using cmake, maybe it links headers in the wrong order?

Comment: @Gh0st, I edited the answer, the above should work, unless othe problems exist

Comment: @Gh0st I added an online sample in the answer https://wandbox.org/permlink/XzUgbwDJ9i058NlH as you can see it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you, it works! I had to also include `controller.hpp` in header files of sorting algorithms (children of SortStrategy).